# Can I use caret RFE result for subsequent random forest with CV?

Tags: r, feature-selection, caret

I've been googling and reading alot about my issue but couldn't find a clear answer.

In order to prevent data leakage, I use caret RFE for feature elimination:

```
rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary
#---- rfe control
rfe_ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                       method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 5, # folds
                       repeats = 3, # iterations
                       verbose = TRUE,
                       returnResamp = "all",
                       saveDetails = TRUE)

#---- rfe
set.seed(164)
rfe_profile <- rfe(df_train[,features_name], 
                  df_train[,target_name],
                  sizes = subsets,
                  rfeControl = rfe_ctrl,
                  metric = "ROC",
                  scale = TRUE)

#---- select final features
features_rfe <- predictors(rfe_profile)[1:30]
```

This works well and tells me how many predictors I should use. Let's say I get the result that 60 features works best. However, according to plots and further analysis (e.g. `pickSizeTolerance`) I know I can use the first 30 features and still having good performance of predictions.

Now, can I use these 30 features (=`features_rfe`) in a subsequent model training step (see code below) since I don't touch the test set until after this step? Or would I introduce data leakage with this step because the model gets trained with pre-selected best features?

```
#---- random forest control
rf_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                        number = 5, # folds
                        verbose = TRUE,
                        returnResamp = "all",
                        classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#---- random forest grid search
rf_grid <-  expand.grid(mtry = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20))

#---- random forest
set.seed(10)
rf_caret_train <- train(df_train[,features_rfe], 
                df_train[,target_name], 
                method = "rf", 
                trControl = rf_ctrl,
                tuneGrid = rf_grid,
                metric = "ROC",
                verbose = TRUE)
#---- make predictions
rf_caret_test_raw <- predict(rf_caret_train, df_test[,features_rfe], type='raw', scale=TRUE)
```

According to this answer here [caret rfe variable selection and test prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60734/caret-rfe-variable-selection-and-test-prediction) it seems to be ok to "Using feature selection on the training set and predicting the test set is fine.". But my feelings tell me "no".

I hope you cann help me.

Best,
Troji

Comment: don't quite understand the issue you have. Ultimately you want a model with predictive power. If you select the features based on only the training set, the test set has not been used in training the model

Comment: thank you for your answer. My question was based on e.g. [this blog post](https://www.nodalpoint.com/not-perform-feature-selection/). But I guess, I missed the point that this problem only arise if I want to predict test error rate based on the training set only. As long as I use a test set which has not been used during training then I'm fine. Am I right?

Comment: yes thats correct. lol the post is from a SO contributer